# Binary Tree path() Implementation

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am working on a programming assignment that requires us to write a path(root, value) method that returns a LinkedList of Direction Enums (left, right) that leads to the target node (value). We are not allowed to create any new fields to make this happen, which is why I've created a pathHelper() method. One of the tests I'm failing is supposed to return: **left, right** as the path but it's returning **left, right, left, right**. I'm not sure why it's counting the steps twice. Any suggestions would be appreciated!
NOTE: This is a Binary Tree, **not** a BST. We are supposed to use an exhaustive DFS approach.

```
    public static <T> LinkedList<BinaryNode.Direction> path(BinaryNode<T> root, T value) {
        if (root == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (root.payload == value) {
            return new LinkedList<>();
        }
        LinkedList<BinaryNode.Direction> list = new LinkedList<>();
        pathHelper(root, value, list);
        return list;
    }

    public static <T> void pathHelper(BinaryNode<T> root, T value, LinkedList<BinaryNode.Direction> list) {
        if (root.left != null) {
            if (root.payload != value) {
                list.add(BinaryNode.Direction.left);
            }
            pathHelper(root.left, value, list);
        } if (root.right != null) {
            if (root.payload != value) {
                list.add(BinaryNode.Direction.right);
            }
            pathHelper(root.right, value, list);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `pathHelper` is walking left *and* right, regardless of value given, so it is walking the **entire tree** depth-first. You need to only walk the path to the target value, same as you do when you need to find where to insert a new value.

Comment: Using `==` and `!=` with objects is likely to fail eventually.  Use the `equals` method instead.  If the value might be null or the payload might be null, use [Objects.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has quite a few errors in it so I'm surprised any test cases are passing. You seem to be storing directions as you search the tree rather than when you find the value.

I suspect you are overcomplicating the problem. If you return a `boolean` from your helper function based on whether the item is found then you can easily add the directions when you return from the recursion:

```
private boolean findPath(BinaryNode<T> node, T value, List<BinaryNode.Direction> directions) {
    if (node == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (node.payload.equals(value)) {
        return true;
    } else if (findPath(node.left, value, directions)) {
        directions.add(0, BinaryNode.Direction.LEFT);
        return true;
    } else if (findPath(node.right, value, directions)) {
        directions.add(0, BinaryNode.Direction.RIGHT);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that this inserts the direction at the start of the list to ensure it's in the correct order. This also allows you to detect where the root has the value because it will return true but the path will be empty.

Comment: This was super helpful! Thank you! I have a tendency to overcomplicate my code.